# Angular solution to downloading dynamically created zip archive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to download a dynamically created zip file using AngularJS?  I can hit the URL using window.open, but this seems very un-Angular, I could use an iframe, but I don't know how I would get a reference to it in my RestService.

What would be a good Angular implementation to allow for downloading of dynamically created files?

```
// Current solution
RestService.createInstance( data )

    .then(function( id) {
        //return RestService.generateArchive( id );
        var url = location.href;
        if( url.indexOf('#') != -1 ) { url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#')); }
        url += '?ID=' + id;
        window.open( url );
    })

    .then(function( success ) {
        // Obviously won't work due to security
    });
```

Also, how would you check if the response was rejected? Seems like you can't, but just in case.

Comment: You can replace the window.open with assigning the url to a scope variable. Then use it in a ng-src for a hidden iframe. Also in the code don't forget to do $sce.trustAsResourceUrl on the url else the iframe won't load.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.  Don't chain my promise, let it return to my directive, add url to $scope, wrap in $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(theactualurl) then in iframe located in directive <iframe ng-src="{{url}}">.  Is that it?  If not do you have an small example?  Even if it is, you should post this as a solution for the credit and for more people to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small sample :

Html :

```
<iframe ng-src="{{url}}" style="display:none"/>
```

JS:

```
$scope.url = 'google.com';
RestService.createInstance( data )

    .then(function( id) {
        //return RestService.generateArchive( id );
        var url = location.href;
        if( url.indexOf('#') != -1 ) { url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#')); }
        url += '?ID=' + id;
        $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    })
```

This should work some remarks :

- ofcourse don't forget to inject $sce
- If you download multiple times from the same url, reset the url between downloads to something like google.com

Comment: Great answer, that is way more Angular.